# Diameter of a weighted Hamming cube

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization

Let $C=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^N$ be the Hamming cube with its usual graph structure, and assume each edge $e=(x,x+\epsilon)$ (where $x\in C$ and $\epsilon$ has one $1$ and $N-1$ zeros) is given a length $\ell(x,\epsilon)$ satisfying the constraints
$$ \sum_\epsilon \ell(x,\epsilon) \le 1 \qquad \forall x\in C.$$
Denote by $d_\ell$ the distance function induced by these lengths.

> **Q1:** What is the growth of the largest possible diameter $D(N)$ for such $(C,d_\ell)$?

I think I can prove a bound $D(N) \lesssim log(N)$, but I wonder if a constant bound could be true.

In fact, this is not the real question I have, but it seemed a reasonable way to get to it. The real question is about functions $f:C\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$(1) \qquad \sum_\epsilon \lvert f(x+\epsilon) - f(x) \rvert \le 1 \qquad \forall x\in C$$
and of vanishing average.

> **Q2:** What is the largest possible value $\lVert f\rVert_\infty$ for such a function?

(My motivation is a toy example to test some concentration inequalities for Markov chains. In some cases I figured the semi-norm $\max_x \sum_\epsilon \lvert f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)\rvert$ should be efficient for the Glauber dynamic (aka lazy random walk) on $C$, but I need the above to get a good spectral gap in the corresponding functional space)

Comment: It is the same question, really: if you bound the diameter of the graph, you bound the function (triviality) but if you have large diameter $D$ of the graph, then $f(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,y)$ has oscillation $D$ for an appropriately chosen $y$ and shifting it to mean $0$ will not drop the norm below $D/2$ (I guess you do not care about constant factors too much).

Comment: $\log N$ is, indeed, trivial (suppose you want to chanke $k$ bits. You definitely can change one of them in the correct way by moving $1/k$ or less. Then you are left with $k-1$ bits to change, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, had to go shopping (why cannot I get a good advice on that problem here???). Constant is also trivial. It is enough to join all zeroes to all ones. Start with zeroes and go up randomly (uniform distribution on admissible moves) to the level $N/2$. The expected cost of each step is at most $2/N$, so the expected total cost is $1$, so more than half of the ways are at $2$ or below. But the distribution of the endpoints is uniform, so more than $1/2$ points at level $N/2$ are reachable at cost $2$. The same for ways down from all ones. Thus you can glue two paths with total cost $4$.

Comment: @fedja Does the $2/N$ step bound still work if length can be negative (it is not really clear from the question if it can, although in Q2 $f$ allegedly may take negative values)?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but you have the sum of *absolute values of differences* (your distance between adjacent $x$ and $y$ is $|f(x)-f(y)|$) and the triangle inequality on $\mathbb R$ is as good as on $[0,+\infty)$, so why do you care? (if you care, we can think of it too, of course :-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like even the sharp upper estimate 1 may be obtained. We use the following

**Lemma.** If $q_0,\dots,q_{N-1}$ are non-negative real numbers such that $q_i-q_{i+1}+q_{i+2}-\dots+q_{i+2s}\geqslant 0$ for all $0\leqslant i\leqslant i+2s\leqslant N-1$, then there exist non-negative numbers $p_0,\dots,p_{N}$ such that $q_i=p_i+p_{i+1}$ for $i=0,\dots,N-1$.

**Proof.** Denote $p_0=t$, then $p_1=q_0-t$, $p_2=q_1-q_0+t$, $p_3=q_2-q_1+q_0-t$, $\dots$, $p_N=q_{N-1}-q_{N-2}+\dots+(-1)^{N-1}q_0+(-1)^Nt$. We need all $p_i$'s be non-negative, this gives certain upper and lower estimates for $t$. They must be consistent. It holds if any lower estimate is consistent with any upper estimate. Say, these two estimates come from the inequalities $p_i\geqslant 0$ and $p_{i+2s+1}\geqslant 0$, where $0\leqslant i< i+2s+1\leqslant N$. Their consistence rewrites as $p_i+p_{i+2s+1}\geqslant 0$ (the left hand side does not depend on $t$), and it is exactly what we supposed.

Note that the assumption of the lemma holds if $q_0\geqslant q_1\geqslant q_2\geqslant \dots \geqslant q_m\leqslant q_{m+1}\leqslant q_{m+2}\dots \leqslant q_{N-1}$ for some $m$. This is what we actually use.

We should find a path of length at most 1 between two opposite vertices, say, from $(0,\dots,0)$ to $(1,\dots,1)$ (all other cases reduce to this by induction in $N$). Sum up the lengths of all $N!$ paths (consisting of $n$ edges), denote the sum by $S$. It suffices to prove that $S\leqslant N!$. Using our lemma, we choose non-negative numbers $p_0,p_1,\dots,p_N$ such that $p_i+p_{i+1}=i!(N-i-1)!$ for all $i=0,\dots,N-1$. Then $S$ equals $\sum_{x\in C} p_{|x|}f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is your sum $\sum_\epsilon \ell(x,\epsilon)$ which does not exceed 1 (and $|x|$ denotes a number of coordinates 1 in $x$). Indeed, if $|x|=i$, $|x+\epsilon|=i+1$, then the edge between $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ belongs to $i!(N-i-1)!$ our paths, and it goes with coefficient $p_i+p_{i+1}$ to our sum.

So, $S$ does not exceed $\sum_{i=0}^N p_i\binom{N}i=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(p_i+p_{i+1})\binom{N-1}i=N(N-1)!=N!$ as desired.

Here is an almost computation-free explanation why Benoît Kloeckner's explicit formula for $p_i$ works.

We have $N+1$ levels $L_0,\dots,L_N$ of vertices of the cube ($L_k$ consists of vertices with the sum equal to $k$), and $N$ levels $P_0,\dots,P_{N-1}$ of edges ($P_i$ consists of edges between $L_i$ and $L_{i+1}$). Choose $i$ at random uniformly in $\{0,1,\dots,N\}$ and after that choose a random edge from a random (uniformly chosen) vertex $v\in L_i$. We get a random edge, and I claim that its level is uniformly distributed. Indeed, the probability to get an edge from $P_k$ equals $\frac1{N+1}(\frac{N-k}N+\frac{k+1}N)=\frac1N$, where the first summand corresponds to $i=k$ and the second to $i=k+1$. Thus the distribution of edges is exactly the same as if we get a random path of length $N$ between $L_0$ and $L_N$ and choose its random edge.

Comment: Great, thanks! There should be a natural choice for the $p_i$, but I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: Ok, got it: one can take $p_i=\frac{i! (N-i)!}{N+1}$. I don't have a nice interpretation though.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I have some explanation which I am less or more satisfied, added to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This was too long for a comment, Fedor Petrov gave a very nice answer with sharp constant (see also fedja's comment with a finite constant), and I just want to give the  reference where the problem was solved back in 2000, for $f$ taking values in an arbitrary normed linear space $B$.

The OP is asking a particular case of what is now called Pisier's inequality for $p=\infty$ without $\log(n)$ factor.

Let $f:\{-1,1\}^{n} \to B,$ where $B$ is linear normed space. Define 
$$
D_{j}f(x) = \frac{f(x)-f(x^{j})}{2},
$$ 
where $x^{j}=(x_{1}, \ldots, -x_{j}, \ldots, x_{n})$, i.e., it puts negative sign in front of $j$-th coordinate. Then Pisier proved

> Theorem (Pisier, 1986). For all $1\leq p \leq \infty$, and any $f:\{-1,1\}^{n} \to B$ we have
>   $$ (\mathbb{E}\|f-\mathbb{E}f\|^{p})^{1p} \leq C
>  \log(n)\left(\mathbb{E}_{x} \mathbb{E}_{y}\|\sum_{j=1}^{n}
>  y_{j}D_{j}f(x) \|^{p}\right)^{1/p}. $$

Later Talagrand (1993) showed that in general for $p<\infty$,  $\log(n)$ factor is sharp. However in case of $B=\mathbb{R}$, $\log(n)$ factor can be removed but with $C=C(p)$ (again $p<\infty$), and for the real-valued functions, the inequality is sometimes called Poincar\'e inequality, because the right hand side (by Khinchin's inequality) can be replaced by a more familiar discrete gradient:
$$
\|\nabla f\|_{p}:= \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} |D_{j}f|^{2}\right)^{p/2}\right)^{1/p}
$$

Finally, Wagner (2000) closed the gap by showing

> Theorem (Wagner, 2000). For $p=\infty$ Pisier's inequality holds without $\log(n)$ factor.

This answers OP,   because for $B=\mathbb{R}$,  Pisier's inequality  becomes  (without $\log(n)$ factor)
$$
\|f-Ef\|_{\infty} \leq C \| \sum_{j=1}^{n}|D_{j}f| \|_{\infty}.
$$

*Pisier, Gilles*, Probabilistic methods in the geometry of Banach spaces, Probability and analysis, Lect. Sess. C.I.M.E., Varenna/Italy 1985, Lect. Notes Math. 1206, 167-241 (1986). [ZBL0606.60008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0606.60008).

*Wagner, R.*, Notes on an inequality by Pisier for functions on the discrete cube, Milman, V. D. (ed.) et al., Geometric aspects of functional analysis. Proceedings of the Israel seminar (GAFA) 1996-2000. Berlin: Springer. Lect. Notes Math. 1745, 263-268 (2000). [ZBL0981.46021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0981.46021).

*Talagrand, M.*, [**Isoperimetry, logarithmic Sobolev inequalities on the discrete cube, and Margulis’ graph connectivity theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01895691), Geom. Funct. Anal. 3, No. 3, 295-314 (1993). [ZBL0806.46035](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0806.46035).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the argument below doesn't answer the right question

Assuming the sum in (1) is over all edges and not only over edges incident to each vertex, Q2 implies Q1, and the answer to Q2 is positive.

For Q2, let $g$ be the linear interpolation of $f$ on the cube graph. Assumption (1) says that the total variation of $g$ is at most $1$. By the coarea formula, the integral over the range of $g$ of the number of preimages is at most $1$.

Since the number of preimages is at least $1$, the range has length at most $1$.

Comment: What is a total variation, the integral of the norm of the gradient? Then why is it at most 1?

Comment: Yes, it is that. Each term in (1) is the integral of the gradient norm over the corresponding edge, so the lhs of (1) is the total variation.

Comment: it is not total, we sum up only by edges incident to $x$

Comment: edited answer accordingly, it's probably a typo in the question

Comment: Probably it is not a typo, a quantifier $\forall x$ is unlikely to appear as a typo twice.

Comment: If it's not a typo, the second question is trivially false. If it is a typo, then the second question is true and proves the first question trivially. So it must be some kind of "typo"

Comment: I don't see how an optimization question can be "false". The sum is indeed over edges adjacent to a vertex. If it where over all edges, the bound 1 would not need coarea formula (each injective path would trivially have length at most 1).

Comment: you're right, sorry